# Get binary in and out of JSON with base64

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, base64

I have built two parsers which are working for everything except some binary blocks. The one goes from a proprietary format into standard json and the other one brings it from json back into the proprietary format.

When I wrote the one which went to json I was just happy to get it all to parse into valid json but worried that I may not have been able to bring the binary sections back, and the concern seems to have come true.

The base64 I believe is necessary or one possible solution as the binary is otherwise too full of characters which json does not like, I think trying to escape them etc would be more challenging than this base64 solution.

So here is a binary block from the original file:

```
cleanbinary = "0\x82\x02\xd80\x82\x01\xc0\xa0"
```

It is brought into base64 like this:

```
import base64    
out = base64.encodebytes(cleanbinary.encode('utf-8'))
print(out)
>> b'MMKCAsOYMMKCAcOAwqA=\n'
```

That, you can turn back into binary:

```
z = base64.decodebytes(out).decode('utf-8')
print(z == cleanbinary)
>> True
```

It needs a step in the middle however which I just can't work out to get it into json in the middle of a loop. Have tried the following:

```
wrapped = '"' + str(out) + '"'
```

So now you have the double quotations which json needs and it is a `str` rather than `bytes`:

```
print(wrapped)
>> '"b\'MMKCAsOYMMKCAcOAwqA=\\n\'"'
```

Now lets say you had plucked this string value out of a json file with Python's json parser. How do you turn it back into a bytes value:

```
b'MMKCAsOYMMKCAcOAwqA=\n'
```

..so that it can be parsed back into binary?

Comment: the simplest way to do this(probably not the best way) is to use [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: `bytes("some_text")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest converting your bytes to a string and back by explicitly decoding and encoding it:

```
out = b'MMKCAsOYMMKCAcOAwqA='

wrapped = f'"{out.decode()}"'
print(wrapped)     # ---> "MMKCAsOYMMKCAcOAwqA="

unwrapped = wrapped.strip('"').encode()
print(unwrapped)   # ---> b'MMKCAsOYMMKCAcOAwqA='
```